# Giving correct python package path name to wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask

I have installed the required package on my system but somehow python is taking some other path to look at the package.

Earlier it was taking python2. So I installed `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

Now Apache is taking python3. I have installed `flask` using pip3 in a virtual environment but when I run it gives no flask found.

I already checked different articles and tried to give a path to the conf file.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess /app3 python-path=/var/www/html/textsummarization:/var/www/html/venv3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias /app3 /var/www/html/textsummarization/app.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/html/textsummarization/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Here is `/var/www/html/textsummarization` is my project folder followed by Python3 site package location where flask has been installed.

Same this has been explained here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps

The error is :

```
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086441 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921] mod_wsgi (pid=27072): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/textsummarization/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086511 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921] mod_wsgi (pid=27072): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/textsummarization/app.wsgi'.
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086854 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086881 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921]   File "/var/www/html/textsummarization/app.wsgi", line 6, in <module>
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086885 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921]     from app import app as application
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086901 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921]   File "/var/www/html/textsummarization/app.py", line 2, in <module>
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086905 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921]     from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify,flash,redirect,url_for
[Fri Apr 19 07:08:01.086919 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 27072:tid 140155700328192] [client 182.73.252.54:49921] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```